# Ruby - Remove items before key in hash

Tags: ruby

It's possible to remove items in hash before defined key? For example:

```
hash = {
  :foo => {"name" => "foo"},
  :bar => {"name" => "bar"},
  :baz => {"name" => "baz"}
}
# ToDo: remove items before :bar
result = {
  :bar => {"name" => "bar"},
  :baz => {"name" => "baz"}
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Hashes maintain their insertion order, but, unless you're doing something to put them in a certain order as they're added it'd be bad/dangerous to assume that `:bar` is in a certain position. This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968).

Comment: I added a second method to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
hash.to_a.drop_while { |k, _| k != :bar }.to_h
```

---

As Mark pointed, In older version of Ruby

```
Hash[*hash.to_a.drop_while { |k, _| k != :bar }]
```

Comment: That's much better than my clunky solution.  Note that you need Ruby 2 for `Array#to_h`.  In older Ruby's you can use `Hash[* array expression here ]`.

Comment: `./app.rb:65:in block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method to_h' for #<Array:0x00000001fa1cd8> (NoMethodError)` :(

Comment: Thanks @MarkReed for the inputs

Answer (score 4):

Ruby Hashes are not really designed to be treated as ordered collections, so this isn't as straightforward as you might expect.  But they do maintain key insertion order, at least since Ruby 1.9, so it's possible.

Here's one way; there are probably better ones:

```
hash.delete(*hash.keys.each_with_index.find do |k, n| 
  n < hash.keys.each_with_index.select{|k,n| k==:bar}[1]
end.map(&:first))
```

First, we ask the hash for its keys with `.keys`, which returns an Array. Then we call `each_with_index` on that Array to associate each item with a numerical index, so now we are iterating over pairs of (key, index).  We search with `.find` for the key we want ( `k == :bar` ) and grab just its index number with `[1]`.

Then we start over and search the same list of (key, index) pairs with `.select` for all the keys whose index is *less* than the index of `:bar`.  This time we want the keys, not the indexes, so we call `.first` on each of those pairs by `map`ping across them.

That gives use the array of keys we want to delete; we use the `*` operator to turn them into a list of arguments and pass them to `.delete` on the Hash to actually remove them.

Comment: Hmm, I understand. Do you have better solution to store elements with ordering? With selecting element by symbol

Comment: Don't use a hash first. Use a structure that honors an order you define, perhaps an array. You can do that by ordering the key/value pairs before you insert them into the hash, but at that point there'd be no reason to delete them from the hash, just delete them first then create the hash. I think you need to think about the problem more as it seems like an XY Problem.

Comment: In case you're not familiar with the term, @Siper: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ruby's little-used [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop).

```
hash = {
  :foo => {"name" => "foo"},
  :bar => {"name" => "bar"},
  :baz => {"name" => "baz"},
  :qux => {"name" => "qux"}
}

key = :baz

hash.select { |k,_| k==key..nil ? true : false }
  #=> {:baz=>{"name"=>"baz"}, :qux=>{"name"=>"qux"}}
```

A second way is as follows.

```
ndx = hash.keys.index(key)
  #=> 2
arr = [*[false]*ndx, *[true]*(hash.size-ndx)]
  #=> [false, false, true, true] 
hash.select { arr.shift }
  #=> {:baz=>{"name"=>"baz"}, :qux=>{"name"=>"qux"}}
```

Comment: Using `? true : false` is a no-op; you can just `select` on `{ |k,_| k==key..nil }`.

Comment: @MarkReed, alas, that won't work, as it's not a flip-flop operator. It just compares `k` with the range `key..nil`. The flip-flop only works in a conditional statement.

Comment: ... ah, right. Sometimes I really appreciate Ruby's Perlish roots.  This is not one of those times.  :)

Comment: You won't rest until every one learns flip-flop operator-eh! It's a good one, did not know about it - the linked article is very nice.

Comment: @Wand, I found a third recent question where it can be used! I'm becoming quite fond of it.